# How to launch whatsapp and facebook messenger window from Flutter to point to a specific contact?

Tags: facebook, flutter, whatsapp

Using url_launcher I can open phone to call a number.

```
 var phone = "+123456789";
 launch("tel://$phone");
```

How can I do the same for facebook messenger and whatsapp?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I found the solution.

To open whatsapp:

```
var whatsappUrl ="whatsapp://send?phone=$phone";
await canLaunch(whatsappUrl)? launch(whatsappUrl):print("open whatsapp app link or do a snackbar with notification that there is no whatsapp installed");
```

To open messenger or facebook:

First get shortened url

If your facebook profile is `facebook.com/yourName`
facebook url would be `fb.me/yourName` and messenger url would be `m.me/yourName`

then you do
`launch("http://$messengerUrl");`

Facebook website will automatically open the link in the app even though it goes trough URL browser. If there is no app installed, it will go to the app/play store

Comment: Oddly, I found that `canLaunch` returns `false` despite it working just fine if you still launch it anyway.

Comment: ^^ true. Better to handle with try catch I guess for now instead of canLaunch()

Comment: I've found that this does indeed launch WhatsApp, but doesn't open the chat bar if the contact is not in your list. Any work around for this?

Comment: How to open just the WhatsApp app, not to specific chats?

Comment: When I open https://m.me/something I get ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME on Android. It seems is trying to do intent:// to open the app

Comment: is there any example to add the message also?

Comment: Do not need to check ```canLaunch(whatsappUrl)``` simply ```launch(whatsappUrl)``` .  ```canLaunch(whatsappUrl)``` returns false.

Comment: make sure for whatsapp the $phone contains the country code without plus for instance  91xxxxxxxxxxx for India

Comment: It opens dialog on android device with two choices browser and messenger. I dont want it. Its not possible to ignore browser and open messenger without that dialog?

Comment: The Plugin used in this answer is url_launcher. https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher/install

Answer (score 10):

To open WhatsApp you can use this plugin: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_launch

**1. Add this to your package's pubspec.yaml file:**

```
dependencies:
    flutter_launch: "^0.3.0"
```

**2. Install it**

```
$ flutter packages get
```

**3. Import it**

```
import 'package:flutter_launch/flutter_launch.dart';
```

**4. Example:**

```
await FlutterLaunch.launchWhatsapp(phone: "5534992019999", message: "Hello");
```

Complete example: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_launch#-installing-tab-

Comment: Is there any way to lunch sharing without a specific phone number?

Comment: `launchWathsApp`? It'd be great to double check method spelling before publishing a package

Comment: @AndreyGordeev I don't know if u are being sarcastic or genuinely suggesting it, but I died laughing

Answer (score 3):

Import package `url_launcher`:

```
 url_launcher: ^6.0.3
```

Import dependency:

```
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
```

Put your url:

```
const _url = 'https://api.whatsapp.com/...';
```

Create your function:

```
void _launchURL() async => await canLaunch(_url) 
    ? await launch(_url) : throw 'Not found $_url';
```

Use, por example in Button:

```
FloatingActionButton(
  onPressed: _launchURL,
  ...
),
```

This works for me! :D

Answer (score 0):

we can use the flutter package https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher

For sending with number and text --->

```
whatsapp://send?phone=XXXXXXXXX&text=Hellothere!
```

For sending only text --->

```
https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=Hellothere!
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Flutter URL lanucher plugin to launch whatsapp app. There you need to add conditions for android and iphone. You can read complete [Flutter tutorial here](https://www.dripcoding.com/flutter-open-whatsapp-and-send-text/).

for android

```
var whatsappURl_android = "whatsapp://send?phone="+whatsapp+"&text=hello";
```

for iphone

```
var whatappURL_ios ="https://wa.me/$whatsapp?text=${Uri.parse("hello")}";
```

first detect the phone OS version - android OR iOS

```
    if(Platform.isIOS){
    // for iOS phone only
    if( await canLaunch(whatappURL_ios)){
       await launch(whatappURL_ios, forceSafariVC: false);
    }else{
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(content: new Text("whatsapp no installed")));

    }

  }else{
    // android , web
    if( await canLaunch(whatsappURl_android)){
      await launch(whatsappURl_android);
    }else{
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(content: new Text("whatsapp no installed")));

    }


  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```dart
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

void _contactViaWhatsApp(context) async {
    String whatsAppUrl = "";

    String phoneNumber = 'your-phone-number';
    String description = "your-custom-message";

    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      whatsAppUrl =
          'whatsapp://wa.me/$phoneNumber/?text=${Uri.parse(description)}';
    } else {
      whatsAppUrl =
          'https://wa.me/+$phoneNumber?text=${Uri.parse(description)}';
    }

    if (await canLaunch(whatsAppUrl)) {
      await launch(whatsAppUrl);
    } else {
      final snackBar = SnackBar(
        content: Text("Install WhatsApp First Please"),
      );
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
    }
  }
```