# How to use Future<bool> in if statement condition?

Tags: flutter, dart

In Flutter, am using "url_launcher" package which uses `Future<bool>` to check if the app can launch other apps.  Within my code I have phone numbers listed, and I want to place an Icon for WhatsApp only if it is installed on the user's device.

```
bool hasWhatsApp() {
    var whatsExists;
    canLaunch('https://api.whatsapp.com/').then((val) => whatsExists = val);
    return whatsExists;
  }
```

am using this function to check inside an if statement to show the icon on the screen or not, however, it keeps returning 'null'.

```
if (phoneNumber.substring(0, 1) != '2' && hasWhatsApp())
                    IconButton(
                      icon: Image.asset('assets/icons/whatsapp.png'),
                      iconSize: Theme.of(context).iconTheme.size,
                      onPressed: () async {
                          await launch(whatsUrl);
                      },
                    ),
```

how can I fix this please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to do cannot work.

Your function `hasWhatsApp` is synchronous, so it returns a value *immediately* when you call it.
Inside that function, you start an asynchronous computation, and when that computation finishes (at a *later* time), it overwrites a local variable. The function has long returned by then.

There is no way you can immediately return a value which is not available until later. It's simply not there.

So, you need to await the future so you can delay making the decision until the value is available.
For example, change your `if` to:

```dart
if (phoneNumber.substring(0, 1) != '2' && 
    await canLaunch('https://api.whatsapp.com/')) {
  ...
}
```

That does mean that you have to make the function containing that `if` asynchronous.
I'm not a Flutter expert, I guess you might need to use a [`FutureBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html).

There is no work-around for asynchrony.

Comment: you are right, it cannot be done, and I cannot use await inside if condition as it is not a pure bool, I have to handle it in a different way. thanks @Irn

Answer (score 0):

You can await `canLaunch` method and convert your function as `async`. Since you make your function `async`, your return type needs to be `Future` Try this:

```
Future<bool> hasWhatsapp() async {
    return await canLaunch('https://api.whatsapp.com/');
}
```

And if you use https://api.whatsapp.com/ as url it will always return true because it can launch it via browser. If you want to check if app is installed I guess you need to use `canLaunch('whatsapp://')` instead. Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/50672986/12709039 this answer for more

Comment: Thank you @Selim, this solution I have already tried, it takes me back to point zero, I cannot use `Future<bool>` inside if statement!

Comment: Well, you can declare a variable before your if statement and then
`var hasWhats = await hasWhatsapp();` and then use it inside your if statement.

Comment: And you can also use `Future<bool>` inside if statement if you put await keyword

Comment: It is a stateless widget, I cannot use a variable with await, it will require me to convert the `Widget build` method into a `Future` so it has to be a function outside the `Widget build` method @Selim

Comment: I want to be able to call it in the conditions part of the if statement, not inside it! @Selim