# Facebook Messenger Id

Tags: facebook, flutter, facebook-graph-api, chat, facebook-messenger

I am developing a flutter application where I want to use Facebook Messenger app for user to user chatting. I am using Facebook login+Firebase Authentication for authenticating my users. I am now rummaging through the Graph API to find a way to get the user's ID (not app-scoped, the universal one). I am going to use the Id to finally launch the messenger app as mentioned in the accepted answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50672710/how-to-launch-whatsapp-and-facebook-messenger-window-from-flutter-to-point-to-a). So please help me find way to launch the messenger app with the link of the user's messenger ID.

If it is not possible with facebook messenger, please mention any third party popular chat application that will register + authenticate my users and help me with the chat.

Comment: There is no way to get the universal user ID.

Comment: Any other way I  can get my users to chat than building up an chat-app from scratch?